# Will my tree survive after have a section of root cut off?

Tags: trees, roots

I have a large ornamental tree in my garden. (I have just bought the bungalow). While I was out a large root (about a foot diameter) which was causing a wall to fall over was cut off. The leaves started to curl at the top of the tree and now further down. It was well watered that day-about a week ago. What else can I do? Will it survive?

Answer (score 5):

All you can do is keep it well watered and keep your fingers crossed. Cutting off a major root from a living tree is always a risk, and only time will tell whether the tree will recover or die, I'm afraid.